# How to write the tie method in tic tac toe?

Tags: java

I am programming a tic tac toe and am stuck in writing the tie().
My winner() is as follows and `diagonalTest()` `rowTest()` and `columnTest()` simply test for their respective names to see which player has won.  However, until someone wins, they all return false and because of that they are false during the game until someone wins.  Given that, how can I write a tie()??

```
public static char getWinner(char p)
{   
     if(diagonalTest() || rowTest() || columnTest())
     return p;

  return ' ';    
}
```

Comment: Please post one (or all) of your *test* methods... also, how you're storing the board. The answer is likely to be a check if every position has a character (in which case no-one can move and it is a tie).

Comment: A tie happens when there are no more valid moves. Checking for this can be done in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tie corresponds to a

```
bool isTie = !(diagonalTest() || rowTest() || columnTest()) && boardIsfull();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an else statement for when all the tests are false:

```
if(diagonalTest() || rowTest() || columnTest()){
    return 'p';
}else{
    return 't'; //t char for tied
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `return 't';` with quotes and the semicolon, right?

Comment: but that would be the case throughout the normal program before board is full and i get a tie message

Comment: In tic-tac-toe, there isn't a tie state without the board being filled, and no winner present. You can call this function when the board is filled to determine if there is a tie. You might want a different function to check after every move if there is a winner.

Comment: yup, i implemented a `boardIsFull()`

Answer (score 0):

Tic tac toe has 9 squares, so 9 steps, have a counter for each step, when counter is 9 test for win, if not tie.